# CSS bootstrap - dropdown - is not seen at bottom of div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to use bootstrap dropdown.
Even though it is dropdown button, dropdown menu is not seen, only head triangle is seen.
You can see the attaced image.
dropdown menu part is out of the parent div. 
any solution?

[image: Image Depicting the Issue]

Comment: add your full code otherwise we won't be able to help

Comment: Thank you for your concern.
In the middle of making sample file, We figure it out that it is due to overflow option!. 
By making it to visible, it has solved.
That was basic of CSS but I am not good at css, I didn't notice it.

Thank you again.

Comment: Glad that you solved it.